# Angular execute get service based on array returned by antoher get with ForkJoin

Tags: arrays, angular, service, get

**Problem:**
Trying to populate a table with information from 2 services:
The first service returns a lista of fabric plans that contain an array with machine operations. The second service is a get that returns a specific operation by id, that is used to get the information about the operation.
The problem is that the service can only receive one id.
How can I populate the table with the operation information knowing that a fabric plan as one or more operations.

The Fabric Plan Model

```
  export class Fabricplan{
  Id: number;
  Description: string; 
  operationsIds: Array<Number> = [];
  DateStart: Date; 
}
```

The service responsible for the post request:

```
getOperation(Id):Observable<Operation[]>{
      return this.http.get<Operation[]>(`${this.operations}${Id}`, httpOptions);
    }
```

The html table is the following:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Number</th>
                        <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Operations</th>
                        <th scope="col">DateStart</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr scope="row" id="table" *ngFor="let fabricplan of fabricplans let i = index" (click)="open(content, fabricplan.id)">
                        <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ fabricplan?.description }}</td>
                        <td>{{ oper_desc[id] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ fabricplan?.dateStart }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

In the fabricplan.component.ts file

```
     ngOnInit() {

    this.fabricplanservice.getfabricplans().subscribe(fabricplans => {
      this.fabricplans = fabricplans;

      const opers_desc$ = this.fabricplans.map( element => 

        this.operationservice.getOperation(element).pipe(
        // map it to the value you want
        map((response) => {
          this.operation = response;
          return this.operation['description'];
        }),
        // replace 404 responses with the  'No fabric plan'
        // if not 404 throw the error again
        catchError((error) => {
          if(error.status === 404){
            return this.empt;
          } else {
            throwError(error);
          }
        }
        )));
        forkJoin(opers_desc$).subscribe((opers_desc) => this.oper_desc = opers_desc);
      });

      this.operationservice.getOperations().subscribe(operation => {
        this.operations = operation;
      });

    }
  }
```